# Full Text Searching with IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

Any idea when full-text searching will be adopted as part of the spec for IndexedDB?  Is it possible to simulate a %LIKE% query as in SQL? It seems like this is a significant limitation.

Comment: I believe it should reopen since this is very common question regarding IndexedDB. IndexedDB do not have full text search feature, but since there is indexing, it is pretty straight forward to implement full text searching.